# twilio flex queued callbacks and voicemail react app not creating task

Tags: plugins, callback, twilio

This is the exact step noted from this readme section.[twilio queue callback flex plugin](https://github.com/twilio-labs/plugin-queued-callbacks-and-voicemail)

There it is instructed to update accountSid variable. But there is no accountSid variable in appConfig.js (code 1). Assuming, I should add the extra variable I did as showed in code 1 (comment ) below.But, the react app didn't work properly,it didn't  show any call baack option or voicemail  in  the task  (image added)[image]
[image]

Step 3: Open appConfig.js with your text editor and update the accountSid variable with your account SID:
var accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

```
  //code 1 
 //assuming here I have to add this line "var accountSid = 
 //'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'" 
 var appConfig = {pluginService: {
 enabled: true,
url: '/plugins',} ,ytica: false, logLevel: 'info',  showSupervisorDesktopView: true,};
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are right that you need to add the `accountSid` to the `appConfig.js` file. It should look like this:

```js
var accountSid = 'ACXXXXX';
var appConfig = {
  pluginService: {
    enabled: true,
    url: '/plugins',
  },
  ytica: false,
  logLevel: 'info',
  showSupervisorDesktopView: true,
};
```

I wonder if you don't see a proper voicemail recording or way to callback because the number they called from, `+266696687`, is invalid. More than invalid, it is in fact an anonymous number. The [numbers 266696687 type out "ANONYMOUS" on a phone keyboard](https://shaun.net/notes/solving-the-mystery-of-calls-from-266696687/).

Comment: I am sorry,but I tried with a valid number too https://imgur.com/a/VwDWe7a ,the same problem was still there.                                                                                  
         The task atleast should show the voicemail recording playback option. The point is,the react app is creating task but not showing any info in the task.                 
          I have followed this tutorial https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/solutions-library/queued-callback-and-voicemail

Comment: the flex instance is not showing information in  TaskInfoPanel on  normal calls also.Can it be enabled with UI react program?

Comment: Is your Flex instance set up correctly? You can do a check up in the Twilio console here: https://console.twilio.com/develop/flex/settings/checkup

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SUe2xgv   this is what come up with the link,is the link correct?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/checkup   followed this link instead. this is the result            https://imgur.com/a/nGztOaa

Comment: Where have we got to with this then? Flex is working as expected except for this plugin? Are there any errors in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Everything works good in another account,that mean browser is ok, plugin itself is ok.

Comment: Oh, there must be something wrong with this account's Flex instance then. Do you have other plugins installed that could be messing with this? Is this account's Flex instance fully up to date?

Comment: its up to date , I only have one external plugin https://imgur.com/a/TUpjbiw , others are default  https://imgur.com/a/eVNqKoE

Comment: I think I’m going to find it difficult to diagnose this. If the plug-in works for you on a different account, then there is something up with the one it doesn’t work on. Consider all the changes you have made to this one and work through them to figure out what has caused the break.

Comment: the problem is not with plugin, Problem is with the flex instance itself. As I said, when a call comes in nothing is visible in TaskInfoPanel.       Also,there are multiple devs working on same flex instance for different project,its hard to track what changes have been made so far.But,It will be easier to find what is the cause of Blank TaskInfoPanel

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser dev tools when running this plugin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228148/discussion-between-jobayer-shajal-and-philnash).

Comment: I didn't find the solution yet,can we continue the discussion?

Comment: What is currently happening with this plugin and your Flex instance? Can you update your question with your latest issues and any relevant screen shots and code. Then mention me and I will be able to take a look.

Comment: I didn't get any changes since we discussed,so we should start from where we left.So is it possible to hide TaskInfoPanel components with UI customization?

Comment: Have you checked out [this tutorial that actually creates a custom `TaskInfoPanel`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/tutorials/adding-components-flex-ui). That might help you with customising the output here.

Comment: Thats helpful,I will try debugging with that.Then I will let you know the end result

Comment: As I was looking for more resource ,I found this https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/components#content-property-and-add-replace-remove-methods            .Following this tutorial I could removeTaskInfoPanel in my another account's(working) flex instance. I made a plugn with Flex.Component.TaskInfoPanel.remove("content");. But ,the account's flex we are debugging doesn't conatainn any removeRequest!!thats strange

Comment: This is the debugging image  https://imgur.com/a/oqgjhx3

Comment: If there is a problem with your flex instance you should contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and they will try to debug what is wrong with it. This does not sound like a programming problem that you are having and I don't think we can solve it here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks,I have created a ticket yesterday

Comment: I have created another related question in stackoverflow,It would be very helpful if you chck this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66624202/twilio-installed-plugins-in-developers-setup